# Rotate d3 chart on click of center

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, rotation

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/sbf8omfx/3/

```
My graph is using d3.js
```

I want to rotate three sections by 120 angle clockwise on click of center circle R as here:

[image]

Is that possible using d3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the element and add an event handler to it:

```
d3.select("#R0").on("click", function(){
    d3.select("svg").style("transform", "rotate(120deg)")
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhLg08h1/).

According to your comment below, if you want it to rotate several times:

```
var angle = 0;
d3.select("#R0").on("click", function(){
    angle += 120;
    d3.select("svg").style("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg)")
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. When I click on it first time, it rotates. But the second time, it doesn't. Is there a way to rotate it as many times as we click on the center button?

Comment: @dang Yes, of course. In the second time it doesn't rotate because it's already at that angle. Simply create a variable that you increase how many degrees you want at the click, and set the rotate using that variable. I edited the answer to show you.